# PagerList error while Creating config File

Tags: android, android-studio, pagedlist

My android Studio is striking off the PagedList as it says it migrated to paging data[image]

```
private fun setUpAdapter() {




    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .setPrefetchDistance(2)
        .build()

    val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(database,config,User::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this).build()
```

Comment: setQuery is not working because of it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.